Is there a when clause context to match an editor's contents in a vscode extension
I am writing a vscode extension that has a menu editor/context contribution. I only want this menu item to be displayed if the contents of the editor matches a regular expression. I read through the documentation and did not see anything. I am wondering if this functionality would be possible in some other way.
Here is what I was hoping for:
"editor/context": [
  {
    "command": "open.something",
    "group": "my.commands",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && editorContent =~ /Open me: ([a-zA-Z]{1,3}\d{5})/"
  }
],

So if the editor had text in it somewhere that looked like the following code snippet, the menu item would be displayed, otherwise it would not.
Open me: ABC00001

I don't know for sure, but doubt this is possible. It would make determining the condition very slow.

You can do this by adding a function to vscode.windows.onDidChangeTextEditorSelection() in your activate function
like this

Then, to set the context, you can access the document text through vscode.window.activeTextEditor.document.getText(). Then you can parse the document text and attempt to find your pattern. Then, use vscode.commands.executeCommand('setContext', 'commandNameHere', 'true/false'), depending on the results of your parsing.
like this

I found this repo helpful while researching a similar topic: https://github.com/vscode-restructuredtext/vscode-restructuredtext/blob/f1a38b697c245ef5a349dc138e2a2077ca289afd/src/editor/setContext.ts#L56
(Original Post: VSCode extension: how to hide/show an item in the context menu?).
Good luck!

Much better to add the actual code to your answer that are linking to jpgs.

Thank you Cass. I will experiment with that solution tomorrow.
